# Angular 4 compatible with Mermaid js?

Tags: angular, typescript, mermaid

I am looking for diagram Javascript library to create some kind of top level dynamic block diagram for my angular project. Can anyone pls tell me if [mermaid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mermaid) is compatible to work with Angular 4? 
Also pls let me know if there are any other good diagram libraries to work on. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Its quite easy to use.

1. Add mermaid to your project: `npm i mermaid`
2. In the view you want to use mermaid, import mermaid and call the init method

Example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as mermaid from "mermaid";

@Component({
    selector: "MermaidTest",
    template: `
        <div class="mermaid">
            graph LR
            A-->B
        </div>`
})
export class MermaidTest implements OnInit {    

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        mermaid.initialize({
            theme: "forest"
        });
    }
}
```

In this case, you have to escape characters like {. If you happen to have the graph content as string anyway, you can use the mermaidAPI instead:

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import * as mermaid from "mermaid";

@Component({
    selector: "MermaidTest",
    template: `<div #mermaid></div>`
})
export class MermaidTest implements AfterContentInit {

    @ViewChild("mermaid")
    public mermaidDiv;

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        mermaid.initialize({
            theme: "dark"
        });

        const element: any = this.mermaidDiv.nativeElement;
        const graphDefinition = "graph TB\na-->b";
        mermaid.render("graphDiv", graphDefinition, (svgCode, bindFunctions) => {
            element.innerHTML = svgCode;
        });
    }
}
```

For more details see https://mermaidjs.github.io/#/mermaidAPI

Comment: Would be super useful if you could make a stackblitz for this.